# Launch the Firefox browser using Web Application with Selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I can able to launch Firefox browser using Windows Application.

But I can’t able to launch Firefox browser using ASP.NET Web Application with same code.

I am getting following error.

**Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms**

I have used following code in Window and Web Application,

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

ISelenium sel = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.gsmarena.com");

sel.Start();

sel.Open("/");
```

It is possible to launch the Firefox browser using Web Application with Selenium?

Comment: What version of the WebDriver are you using?

Comment: selenium-dotnet-2.45.0

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try,

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.gsmarena.com");
```

Comment: Driver initialization itself loading more time.. IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  not moving next line.

Comment: I believe that you have performed `driver.Quit();` after your previous tests.

Comment: Code working fine when i run locally. After deployed in IIS, not working.

Comment: @Vinoth were you able to get it fixed?